# Access AWS Support Service using ajax

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm trying to create a case using "create case" option using the AWS support service. I have a web application from which i want to create AWS support tickets. They only hurdle that is standing in my way is CORS (no surprises there :p) my question is, is there a way that i can create `AWS` support tickets (create case) by sending an ajax request to the end point? if yes, then how?

Do I need to enable the CORS support at the AWS end? how can i enable it?

what i have tried so far

```
    $(function(){

        $.getScript( "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aws-sdk/2.41.0/aws-sdk.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
            console.log( data ); // Data returned
            console.log( textStatus ); // Success
            console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
            console.log( "Load was performed." );
            alert('loaded');
            var support = new AWS.Support(options = {
                endpoint :'END_POINT',
                accessKeyId :'SOME KEY',
                secretAccessKey :'YET ANOTHER KEY'
            });
            var params = {
                communicationBody: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
                subject: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
                attachmentSetId: 'STRING_VALUE',
                categoryCode: 'STRING_VALUE',
                ccEmailAddresses: [
                'STRING_VALUE',
                /* more items */
                ],
                issueType: 'STRING_VALUE',
                language: 'STRING_VALUE',
                serviceCode: 'STRING_VALUE',
                severityCode: 'STRING_VALUE'
            };


            support.createCase(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err){ // an error occurred
                    alert('error occured');
                console.log(err, err.stack);
            }
            else   {
                alert('success');
                console.log(data);           // successful response
            }
        });
    });//loadScript Ends


});//document ready ends
```

Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on this also.  The issue is that you need to include the build file for aws.support from here: https://sdk.amazonaws.com/builder/js/

At this time, I am able to download the js with the createCase, but not able to link it to the same example that you are doing.  If the js is posted out to a web server, I am thinking that you can change the first line of code to point to that js file, but that is what I am working on now.